# FULL TEXT Search – usefulness of Ranking

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

RANK column indicates how well a row matched the selection criteria.

```
SELECT *   
FROM CONTAINSTABLE ( someTable, *, 'surf OR life' ) AS ct 
   INNER JOIN someTable ON
     ct.[KEY] = someTable.i
```

Assuming we run the above query, I would expect that the two rows returned by a query ( one containing string `life` and other containing string `surf`) will be ranked the same, but they aren’t!

a) For that reason, isn’t RANK column helpful only for comparing RANK values for rows containing the same word/phrase? Namely, if the above query returned two rows, where row `A` contains 5 occurrences of a word `surf`, while row `B` contains 6 occurrences  of a word `life`, then we can’t really rely on RANK values to tell us which row was a better match ( since row B could be ranked lower even though it matched selection criteria better )?

b) I assume that two rows, both containing one occurrence of word `surf` will always have equal RANK values, regardless of whether one of the rows contains 1000 characters in a string, while other only 10 characters?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

Check 2008 Books Online ***How Search Query Results Are Ranked*** for details on ranking and why that happens (see the detailed formula).

You could do more tests of your data:

'life OR surf'

Check out the CONTAINS syntax for more ideas, or weight those you care about.

Your answers:

a) the RANK formula is much more complex than you suggest.

b) the RANK formula suggests otherwise.